# Is there only one way to divide an equilateral triangle into congruent fourths?

Tags: geometry, triangles, dissection

Suppose we wish to divide an equilateral triangle into fourths, such that each piece is congruent. (Let's also require connectedness.) One way to do this is to connect the medians, forming one inverted triangle in the center and three at the corners. Is this the *only* way? Are there any other ways to divide an equilateral triangle into congruent fourths?

Comment: Take three line segments from one vertex to the opposite edge.

Comment: @JohnDouma Those won't be congruent.

Comment: You can deform the common sides between two triangles in such a way to keep them congruent.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca The issue is, if you're starting from the connect-the-medians solution, you can't get two disjoint pairs of adjacent triangles.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger You're right, that won't work.

Comment: I think you mean 'the midpoints of the sides", not "the medians". A median is usually a line connecting a vertex to the midpoint of the opposite side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on how strict you are with your notion of connectedness, here are four congruent sets whose closures are connected and whose interiors are disjoint:

[image]

Comment: Nice! But: if these shapes are all taken to contain the point at which the three pieces meet (which is not possible since that point is the same point for red + green, and for yellow + orange) then they are contractible; otherwise, they are disconnected. Either way, where is the nontrivial $\pi_1$?

Comment: Good point - sloppy wording on my part, I'll edit. Do you know of nice terminology for the notion of not-quite-connectedness that applies here?

Comment: Well, the point is called a cut point (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_point). I don't know if there's any name in particular for a space with a cut point.

Comment: Cool! That's a pretty unexpected configuration. How did you find it?

Comment: I was inspired by [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j9W7.png) decomposition of an equilateral triangle into 5 pieces, and realized that the problem of writing a union of finitely many congruent cells as a collection of subsets related to each other by one of a finite set of isometries could be expressed as a not-too-large SAT instance; I wrote some code to generate such instances, and then plugged it into an off-the-shelf solver in Python. One of the solutions had remarkably few edge-connected components in each piece (compared to e.g. [this](https://i.imgur.com/bn5yW7X.png)).

Comment: Of course, this still leaves open the question of a strongly connected decomposition. (Call a piece _weakly_ connected if the closure of its interior is connected, and _strongly_ connected if its interior is connected; I think that captures the idea well enough.) I strongly suspect this is impossible, which will require an impossibility proof